# developing shiny app as a package and deploying it to shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, devtools

I am developing a shiny app and since I wanted to use automated testing and documentation of the function, I started to develop the interface within a package (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719503/automatic-documentations-of-functions-for-shiny-app-using-rstudio?noredirect=1#comment62920775_37719503)).

I develop this shiny app within RStudio and I have a `server.R` file which I can click on the **Run App** button within RStudio and everything works. I commit my package to a github repository and from this point I want to install it on my *R shiny server* using `devtools` and `install_github` function.

Now I am wondering how to start my app within the server. I was naively thinking to install the package and pointing to the `server.R` file, but this is somehow not working. Not sure where the problems are.

My second try was creating a file called `app.R` in a folder accessible by the shiny server and in this file I basically load my package, shiny and other needed packages but it somehow complains because of missing variables...

Can somebody give me an advice? I am also happy to answer any question since I am not sure how to ask for this problem properly. 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT Deploying to shiny server**

Since *Colin D* was asking in the comments, how to deploy these packages on a shiny server, I wanted to demonstrate how I do this.

First of all I install my package on the shiny server directly via the command line as **root** with the following command.

```
su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('user/shinypackage')\""
```

The next step is to change the owner of the package folder

```
chown -R shiny:shiny /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shinypackage/
```

Then I restart the shiny server since this was sometimes problematic with caching or so.

```
systemctl restart shiny-server
```

These are the steps I do when I update my shiny app. I do this normally again as root in a single line

```
su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('user/shinypackage')\"" &  chown -R shiny:shiny /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shinypackage/ & systemctl restart shiny-server
```

One thing we still need to do is to setup the directory in the `shiny-server.conf` file. I just added the package path+the application directory where the `ui.R` and `server.R` is saved.

```
  location /shinypackage {
    app_dir /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shinypackage/application;
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
  }
```

Then I have to restart the server again by using `systemctl restart shiny-server`.

This is in use on a Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I do this as a matter of routine. I put my app files in the `inst` directory of the package and include a function called `launch_application` which merely calls `runApp` with my desired default arguments. The app files are found via `system.file`

Comment: Sounds like what I am looking for. What files are in the `inst` folder then? Just the call of the `launch_application` function and the `library` calls? Since I put each function in an extra file in the `R` folder, I hoped I can export them and just load my package...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When I make shiny applications as a stand-alone package, I usually organize the files as so:

In the R directory:

- All of my methods to support the application (these should be exported if they will be used in either the `ui.R`, `server.R`, or `global.R` files)
- A `launch_application` function

The definition of `launch_application` is similar to:

```
launch_application <- function(x, ...)
{
  shiny::runApp(appDir = system.file("application", package = [my_pkg]),
                ...)
}
```

In the inst directory

- `application/server.R`
- `application/ui.R`
- `application/global.R`

After building and installing the package, I then just need to run

```
library(my_pkg)
launch_application(...)
```

Comment: Ahhh, now I got it... So `server.R` and `ui.R` go into the `application` folder and only my functions staying in the `R` folder. I will give it a try though...

Comment: Maybe one more specific question... I am using `DT::renderDataTable` in my server file. Where should I actually load the library? I was first putting `DT` as a dependency in my `DESCRIPTION` file, now, since I moved the `server.R` into the application directory, while building the package complains, I do not use all dependencies.

Comment: List `DT` under `Suggests` and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, and it took me a while to figure out that I have to set the `app_dir` in the `shiny_server.conf` to the output of `system.file('application', package='my_pkg')`... Since I was creating a file `app.R`, loading the package and using your suggestion `launch_application` function but it ended in `ERROR: Key / already in use`... Not it is working! Thanks

Comment: How would you deploy an app with this format on shiny server?

Comment: I've never used shiny server. So I wouldn't be able to give an informed answer. This may be a good topic to pose as a separate question.

Comment: @ColinD I updated my answer on how I deploy the package directly on the server. Together with a github account, this works in a single line. Write me back if you have questions

Comment: Will this work if using app.R with combined ui and server objects, rather than separately stored in ui.R and server.R ?

Comment: Yes.  See the `appDir` argument of `?shiny::runApp` for details.

Answer (score 32):

There is already an accepted answer with many votes, but I'd like to add a few things, so I'll answer myself as well. For more information, you can read my article [Supplementing your R package with a Shiny app](https://deanattali.com/2015/04/21/r-package-shiny-app/).

This is the folder structure I use:

```
- mypacakge
  |- inst
      |- myapp
         |- ui.R
         |- server.R
  |- R
     |- runApp.R
     |- ...
  |- DESCRIPTION
  |- ...
```

Inside the `R/` folder is where I place all the non-shiny code. The code for the shiny app itself lives in `inst/`. The `R/runApp.R` file is defined as

```
#' @export
runExample <- function() {
  appDir <- system.file("myapp", package = "mypackage")
  if (appDir == "") {
    stop("Could not find myapp. Try re-installing `mypackage`.", call. = FALSE)
  }

  shiny::runApp(appDir, display.mode = "normal")
}
```

(You can see this in action; for example, [shinyalert](https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert) uses this structure for its demo app).

In a comment, you asked how can this be deployed on a shiny server. It's simple, you can simply have a file `/srv/shiny-server/myapp.app.R` that calls and runs that package (after you've installed the package on the server):

```
dir <- system.file("myapp", package = "mypackage")
setwd(dir)
shiny::shinyAppDir(".")
```

(You can see this in action as well, code [here](https://github.com/daattali/shiny-server/blob/master/shinyalert-demo/app.R))

Comment: Hi, thanks @DeanAttali, for your code !
I have documented the file myapp/global.R. It contains all the functions used by the application. How can add them to the documentation of the package ?

Comment: Thank you, @DeanAttali, your explanation helps me.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of packages with proof-of-concept Shiny demos are not designed for deployment on Shiny Server, but instead, include something like this in a function meant to be run from RStudio:

```
fooRun <- function() {
   app <- shinyApp(appUI, appServer)
   runApp(app, launch.browser = TRUE, ...)
}
```

This function won't work in Shiny Server (you can't run `runApp` within `runApp`) but it gives some clues as to how to create an app.R that can act as a placeholder to use in `/srv/shiny-server/foo/app.R`

```
library("foo")
shinyApp(ui = foo:::appUI, server = foo:::appServer)
```